# Facebook Business SDK PHP - Cannot Fetch Campaign Fields

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-business-sdk

I am trying to get the campaign names of an ad account with the following code

```
$account = new AdAccount($account_id);
$cursor = $account->getCampaigns();
echo sizeof($cursor);

// Loop over objects
foreach ($cursor as $campaign) {
    echo $campaign->{CampaignFields::NAME}.PHP_EOL;
}
```

The cursor has the correct number of campaigns but I get empty field values. Same applies when I try to get the Ad Account fields.

Does anybody know why is this happening? I am using the latest version of API (v5.0)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the field you want to request by the API in the method, as example:

```
$cursor = $account->getCampaigns(['id','name']);
```

Refer also to the [AdAccountsCampaigns](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-business-sdk/blob/master/examples/AdAccountCampaignsEdge.php) example for further details about the usage of `fields` and `params`:

```
$fields = array(
  'name',
  'objective',
);
$params = array(
  'effective_status' => array('ACTIVE','PAUSED'),
);
echo json_encode((new AdAccount($id))->getCampaigns(
  $fields,
  $params
)->getResponse()->getContent(), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Hope this help